# Шифрование cooбщeний

Tags: php, шифрование, md5, sha1

Как шифровать сообщения пользователей (чтобы они не были читабельны в базе данных mysql) которые переписываются между собой, и конечно же сделать читабельным только для самих пользователей. Имеется ли работоспособный пример?

Comment: Указанные вами функции не используются для шифрования! Это функции хеширования. Наверное в сторону openssl нужно смотреть https://www.google.ru/search?q=php+openssl+%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: используйте любой надежный метод шифрования. основная проблема у вас будет в хранение ключей. они должны хранится только у клиентов,  только тогда никто не сможет прочитать сообщения кроме них.

Comment: Изучайте - https://habrahabr.ru/post/257439/

Comment: @n.osennij, примеров то там как раз и нет.

Comment: a php.net на что?

Comment: А в инструкции на хабре всё-всё расписано.